# Combo box connected to postgreSQL, how to?

Tags: php, postgresql

How can I pick up values from a postgreSQL database and place them in a combo box using php?

Comment: Both of these are easily googled. Just separate them and look up one, then the other.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full example:

myPHP.php

```
<?php 

            $db = pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=contacts user=contacts password=firstphp'); 

            $query = "SELECT * FROM friends"; 

            $result = pg_query($query); 
            if (!$result) { 
                echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>"; 
                echo pg_last_error(); 
                exit(); 
            } 
           $list_data = null;

            while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                $list_data .= "<option value=\"".$myrow['id']."\">".$myrow['name']."</option>"; 
            } 


           // assign it to some var, I dont know what king of template you are using
          $t->assign('LIST_DATA',$list_data); 
    ?>
```

myFile.tpl

```
<select name="one">
     {LIST_DATA} 
</select>
```

Comment: And how can I execute this php code in a .tpl file? Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @Marco Paiva check my updated answer. Still that is only the concept, you will need to tailor it to your template engine parser. Consider accepting answers that answered your question.